# Update text every minute cordova plugin local notifications

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I try to update text every minute with cordova-plugin-local-notifications in phone`scheduleMinutely = function () {
    var sound = device.platform == 'Android' ? 'file://ting.wav' : 'file://beep.caf';
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: localStorage.text,
        title: 'Note',
        text: localStorage.text,
        every: 'minute',
        sound: sound,
        icon: 'res://icon',
        smallIcon: 'res://ic_popup_sync'
    });
};`

```
localStorage.text = 0;
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
   cordova.plugins.notification.local.on('schedule', function (notification) {
      console.log('onschedule', arguments);
      localStorage.text ++;
   });
});
```

The first time, it show `0`, but the second time after 1 minute, it show `0`, not `1`, i see it not return the schedule.

Thank you for helping!!!

Answer (score 0):

The point is, you can not use dynamic texts in notifications.

If you want to use different texts, you have to create for each text an individual notification. Maybe it is better in this case to use push notifications.

But be aware, there are limitations on each platform of how many notifications you can place.